# Can I call Options Framework in footer.php?

Tags: theme-options

I have integrated the [Options Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) into my theme.

Can I call `of_get_option(...)` in footer.php?

Comment: why not to simply try it?

Comment: I have and it didn't work.

Comment: then you can edit the question to make it relevant by adding your code, because as you saw, you can call it there, it is just the results are not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the function in any template file in your theme folder.